# Ember.js: Transition somewhere else if a model exists

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to implement logic that goes something like this:

If some data does not exist yet, take them to the data entry page. If the data has already been entered, redirect them somewhere else.

I'm doing it something like this:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    beforeModel: function () {
      var context = this;
      this.store.find("data").then(function (data) {
        var datum = data.get("firstObject");
        if(datum) {
          context.transitionTo("application.welcome");
        } else {
          context.transitionTo("application.enterData");
        }
      });
    }
});
```

I have a feeling I am not doing it right. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: hmm, if you described your real problem (what you want to achieve), then it would be easier to give you an advise! :)

Comment: The real world problem is that I want to check if a model exists, and redirect to X, else redirect to Y.

Comment: I've updated it to be more "real-world"-like

Comment: I thought I had to return a promise like in the model hook, that's what is confusing me.